# Stripe Django: How to charge the existing customer with a plan

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I am trying to charge an **existing** Stripe customer with an updated credit card (Stripe token) for a new subscription plan. Most of the examples given are for creating a **new** customer and charging the customer for a new plan, but I want to charge an existing customer.

```
new_customer = stripe.Customer.create(
                email=request.POST['stripeEmail'],
                plan = 'plan_DgV0NXZk7vlMMG',
                card=request.POST['stripeToken']
            )
```

Answer (score 2):

Subscriptions use the `default_source` by default.  So you would [Create a new Customer Card Source](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card) and set it to the default or simply replace the default source by setting the `source`-attribute when you use the [Update Customer API Endpoint](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_customer).  Finally, you can [Create a new Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription).

Comment: thanks. How can I delete the subscription. As per Stripe documentation, following code will delete the subscription but I don't see any customer here.

    import stripe
    stripe.api_key = "sk_test_UjdekkUi84zRH0gmgFfqoNWN"
    sub = stripe.Subscription.retrieve("sub_DiPMUHzNt1CHYC")
    sub.delete()